# What does the MediaRecorder start failed 38 mean and how do I solve it?

Tags: android, video-encoding, mediarecorder

I am getting this message in my logcat.

```
E/MediaRecorder(25487): start failed: -38
```

The thing is, that my mediarecorder runs just fine. However, I am a bit worried as I have no clue what that means. Can someone help? How can I fix that?

Comment: This question had good discussion in following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971817/mediarecorder-start-failed-38