# MediaRecorder start failed: -38

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

i searched to check if this question is no dup , i see some has no answer and others did not help.

this is my code :

```
private void startRecording()
{
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
              mFileName += "/recordedHeckPost_.3gp";

            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);                  

                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                    //Thread.sleep(2000);
                    mRecorder.start();                  
        }
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }     
            catch(IllegalStateException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private void stopRecording()
{
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
}
```

After running this code (On Nexus 5) i get the below start **failed -38 exception**:

```
05-31 18:17:39.404: E/MediaRecorder(2464): start failed: -38
05-31 18:17:39.404: W/System.err(2464): java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-31 18:17:39.404: W/System.err(2464):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found the solution , it appears i had some other service in the background which is using 
AudioRecord and uses the mic as well.... so thats the -38 :)

Comment: Which background service was this in particular?

Comment: It was one of my my app services not OS

Comment: Found it! From another app I tested whose icon I had hidden!Damn I would never never realized it without the answer about other service in background.Thanks!

Comment: how can i find that other service running in background for recording or using mic?

Comment: just check in your source code of your application for the strings "AudioRecord" or "MediaRecorder" .... or some other way to find if you have code that uses the mic....

Comment: Did you find any solution to fix this without removing the background services?. I am using https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP to detect the pitch from the microphone when recording the video. So can you please help me out to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that error (`MediaRecorder: start failed: -38`) was appearing after switching to second camera when I forgot to release MediaRecorder during closing (first) camera:

```
mediaRecorder?.release()
mediaRecorder = null
```