# Unable to record video with media recorder android

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to record video using media recorder.
When ever i try to record video it crashed with the following logcat.

> 05-20 14:28:43.432: E/MediaRecorder(4281): start failed: -38 05-20
>   14:28:43.432: D/AndroidRuntime(4281): Shutting down VM 05-20
>   14:28:43.432: W/dalvikvm(4281): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x415c5d88) 05-20 14:28:43.462:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 05-20 14:28:43.462:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4281): Process: com.abc.def, PID:
>   4281 05-20 14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException 05-20 14:28:43.462:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4281):   at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native
>   Method) 05-20 14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):   at
>   com.abc.def.PrivateChatDialog.startVideoRecording(PrivateChatDialog.java:1413)
>   05-20 14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):   at
>   com.abc.def.PrivateChatDialog$3.onClick(PrivateChatDialog.java:198)
>   05-20 14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569) 05-20 14:28:43.462:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4281):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18570) 05-20
>   14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743) 05-20
>   14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-20
>   14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 05-20 14:28:43.462:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4281):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212) 05-20
>   14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-20
>   14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 05-20 14:28:43.462:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4281):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   05-20 14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 05-20
>   14:28:43.462: E/AndroidRuntime(4281):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is the code i am using to capture video.

```
protected void startVideoRecording() throws IOException {
        if(mrec==null)
        mrec = new MediaRecorder(); // Works well
        mCamera.unlock();
        mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
      mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mrec.setOutputFile(getVideoFileName());
        mrec.setVideoSize(320, 280);
        mrec.prepare();
        mrec.start();
        videoRecording = true;
    }
```

I have tried a lot and searched a lot but could not find the solution.
What I found [was this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971817/mediarecorder-start-failed-38)

But I do not have any background service recording audio.
Please help me find a solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the function as follows:

```
public void startVideoRecording() throws IOException {
        mrec = new MediaRecorder(); // Works well
        mCamera.unlock();
        mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mrec.setOrientationHint(90);
        String path = getVideoFileName();
        mrec.setOutputFile(path);
        mrec.prepare();
        mrec.start();
        videoRecording = true;
    }
```

After this also the app crashed, then a restart of phone did the trick, now everything works well.